# Joining tables with recent date for each row then weighted averaging

Tags: sql, oracle, join, aggregation

There are three tables, such as  equip_type , output_history, and time_history in Oracle DB.
Is there a way to join the three tables as shown below at (1)  and then to get weighted average as shown below at (2)?

```
--equip_type table and the date
CREATE TABLE equip_type  (  
  EQUIP_TYPE VARCHAR(60),    
  EQUIP VARCHAR(60)
  );
INSERT INTO equip_type  VALUES ('A','e1');

-- output_history and data
CREATE TABLE output_history (  
  EQUIP VARCHAR(60),     
  MODEL VARCHAR(60),     
  Data1 VARCHAR(60),        
  QUANTITY  NUMBER(10) 
  );
INSERT INTO output_history VALUES ('e1','m1','20180103',10);
INSERT INTO output_history VALUES ('e1','m1','20180106',20);


--time_history table and data
CREATE TABLE time_history (  
  EQUIP VARCHAR(60),     
  MODEL VARCHAR(60),       
  Data2 VARCHAR(60),    
  time NUMBER(10)
  );
INSERT INTO time_history VALUES ('e1','m1','20180101',6);
INSERT INTO time_history VALUES ('e1','m1','20180105',5);
```

(1) How to get joined table as below?

```
 EQUIP MODEL DATE1  QUANTITY   DATE2   TIME  TYPE
 ---- ---- ---------- ------  -------- ----  ----
  e1    m1  20180103  10      20180101   6    A
  e1    m1  20180106  20      20180105   5    A
```

For each row in OUTPUT_HISTORY, *the most recent row at the point of the DATE1*in TIME_HISTORY is joined.

(2) Then, With the joined table above, how to get weighted average of TIME?

```
(QUANTITY * TIME) / sum of QUANTITY group by TYPE, MODEL

 for example,(10×6 + 20×5)÷(10+20) for equip type A and model m1
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses analytic functions to get the most recent record and then simple aggregation

```
select sum(quantity * time) / sum(quantity)
from output_history oh left join
     (select th.*,
             row_number() over (partition by equip, model order by date2 desc) as seqnum
      from time_history th
     ) th
     on oh.equip = th.equip and oh.model = th.model and th.seqnum = 1
group by equip, model;
```

Comment: Thank you for your  code, But after executing your code, Date2 shows all 20180105. For Date1 20180103 , the most recent Date2 shoud be 20180101.

Comment: Thank you for your edited code, But still the Date 2 shows all 20180105.